# A quick way to convert a block of numbers or characters into a matrix (without using ampersand &)

Tags: matrices

I have a block of numbers like this (actually it is a Hadamard matrix of order 12). What is the quickest way to convert this block into a matrix? Of course one can do it with a matrix environment like `bmatrix`, `pmatrix` etc by adding ampersand & between the numbers, but I am looking for a solution by just coping the block.

```
1 -1 -1 -1  -1 -1 -1 -1  -1 -1 -1 -1
1  1 -1  1  -1 -1 -1  1   1  1 -1  1
1  1  1 -1   1 -1 -1 -1   1  1  1 -1
1 -1  1  1  -1  1 -1 -1  -1  1  1  1
1  1 -1  1   1 -1  1 -1  -1 -1  1  1
1  1  1 -1   1  1 -1  1  -1 -1 -1  1
1  1  1  1  -1  1  1 -1   1 -1 -1 -1
1 -1  1  1   1 -1  1  1  -1  1 -1 -1
1 -1 -1  1   1  1 -1  1   1 -1  1 -1
1 -1 -1 -1   1  1  1 -1   1  1 -1  1
1  1 -1 -1  -1  1  1  1  -1  1  1 -1
1 -1  1 -1  -1 -1  1  1   1 -1  1  1
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The [`spalign`](https://ctan.org/pkg/spalign) package is very useful for this: It allows to create a matrix by separating the columns by spaces and lines by semicolons, e.g.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{spalign}
\begin{document}
\[
  \spalignmat{
1 -1 -1 -1  -1 -1 -1 -1  -1 -1 -1 -1;
1  1 -1  1  -1 -1 -1  1   1  1 -1  1;
1  1  1 -1   1 -1 -1 -1   1  1  1 -1;
1 -1  1  1  -1  1 -1 -1  -1  1  1  1;
1  1 -1  1   1 -1  1 -1  -1 -1  1  1;
1  1  1 -1   1  1 -1  1  -1 -1 -1  1;
1  1  1  1  -1  1  1 -1   1 -1 -1 -1;
1 -1  1  1   1 -1  1  1  -1  1 -1 -1;
1 -1 -1  1   1  1 -1  1   1 -1  1 -1;
1 -1 -1 -1   1  1  1 -1   1  1 -1  1;
1  1 -1 -1  -1  1  1  1  -1  1  1 -1;
1 -1  1 -1  -1 -1  1  1   1 -1  1  1
  }
\]
\end{document}
```

If you also want to avoid the semicolons, you can ask TeX to insert a semicolon at every end of line:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{spalign}
\begin{document}
\[
  \begingroup\endlinechar=`\;\spalignmat{
1 -1 -1 -1  -1 -1 -1 -1  -1 -1 -1 -1
1  1 -1  1  -1 -1 -1  1   1  1 -1  1
1  1  1 -1   1 -1 -1 -1   1  1  1 -1
1 -1  1  1  -1  1 -1 -1  -1  1  1  1
1  1 -1  1   1 -1  1 -1  -1 -1  1  1
1  1  1 -1   1  1 -1  1  -1 -1 -1  1
1  1  1  1  -1  1  1 -1   1 -1 -1 -1
1 -1  1  1   1 -1  1  1  -1  1 -1 -1
1 -1 -1  1   1  1 -1  1   1 -1  1 -1
1 -1 -1 -1   1  1  1 -1   1  1 -1  1
1  1 -1 -1  -1  1  1  1  -1  1  1 -1
1 -1  1 -1  -1 -1  1  1   1 -1  1  1
  }\endgroup%
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: To obtain a bracketed matrix one should add  `\spaligndelims[]` right after `\[`.

Answer (score 17):

I'll add to @MarcelKrüger's good answer the right alignment option `[r]` for nice output.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{spalign}
\begin{document}
\[
  \begingroup\endlinechar=`\;\spalignmat[r]{
1 -1 -1 -1  -1 -1 -1 -1  -1 -1 -1 -1
1  1 -1  1  -1 -1 -1  1   1  1 -1  1
1  1  1 -1   1 -1 -1 -1   1  1  1 -1
1 -1  1  1  -1  1 -1 -1  -1  1  1  1
1  1 -1  1   1 -1  1 -1  -1 -1  1  1
1  1  1 -1   1  1 -1  1  -1 -1 -1  1
1  1  1  1  -1  1  1 -1   1 -1 -1 -1
1 -1  1  1   1 -1  1  1  -1  1 -1 -1
1 -1 -1  1   1  1 -1  1   1 -1  1 -1
1 -1 -1 -1   1  1  1 -1   1  1 -1  1
1  1 -1 -1  -1  1  1  1  -1  1  1 -1
1 -1  1 -1  -1 -1  1  1   1 -1  1  1
  }\endgroup%
\]
\end{document}
```

> [image]